# How does DeepNeuralNetworkLearning of Accor.Net work?

Tags: accord.net

I was trying to follow the code in `DeepNeuralNetworkLearning` class and couldn't follow the code.

I suspect that it trains the network partially (like from layer 3 to 5 for a network consisting of 5 layers). That partial network is trained using backprop or Rprop.

It is unclear for me how to use it properly. Should we start training from input layer to output layers or vice versa?

Lastly, if the technique used in this class has a name in Neural Network literature, does someone know it?

Comment: This class was meant to be used with the layerwise pre-training using deep belief networks from Hinton (2006). Needless to say that the neural network literature has now evolved a lot, and this network implementation has not been updated since then. 

The Accord.Neuro namespace is currently being re-written to use TensorFlow.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking at the same problem but as you noted there is very little documentation on how to use this class properly. I have come across some examples, but they all use one hidden layer which is ironic as the class is meant for deep learning. In any case the example below will help you understand how to put the code together and then you can modify it to your needs.

You can change the algorithm to any network style you want by setting the property teacher.Algorithm. i.e for RPROP use ParallelResilientBackpropagationLearning.

You then use teacher.LayerIndex to set the layers to train which is normally set to network.Machines.Count - 1

To train the network you use teacher.RunEpoch to train on the whole batch and repeat until the return error is low enough.

See Accord .Net Framework class info here:-
[DeepNeuralNetworkLearning Class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Neuro_Learning_DeepNeuralNetworkLearning.htm)

[DeepBeliefNetworkLearning Class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Neuro_Learning_DeepBeliefNetworkLearning.htm)

---

```
   ' Training data
        Dim inputs As Double()() = {New Double() {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1},
                                    New Double() {1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1},
                                    New Double() {1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1},
                                    New Double() {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1},
                                    New Double() {-1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1},
                                    New Double() {-1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1}}
        Dim outputs As Double()() = {New Double() {1, -1},
                                     New Double() {1, -1},
                                     New Double() {1, -1},
                                     New Double() {-1, 1},
                                     New Double() {-1, 1},
                                     New Double() {-1, 1}}

        ' Generation of network
        Dim network = New DeepBeliefNetwork(inputs.Length,          ' The input layer dimension
                                            New Integer() {4, 2})   ' Dimension of the hidden layer And output layer

        ' Generation of learning algorithm of DNN
        Dim teacher = New DeepNeuralNetworkLearning(network)
        teacher.Algorithm = Function(ann, i) New ParallelResilientBackpropagationLearning(ann)
        teacher.LayerIndex = network.Machines.Count - 1

        ' Repeat learning 5000 times
        Dim layerData As Double()() = teacher.GetLayerInput(inputs)
        For i As Integer = 0 To 4999
            Dim dError As Double = teacher.RunEpoch(layerData, outputs)
            lblMean.Text = "Error: " + Format(dError, "0.000")
            Application.DoEvents()
        Next

        ' Update weights
        network.UpdateVisibleWeights()

        ' Compute the test data in the learning network is the probability that belong to each class
        Dim input As Double() = {1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1}
        Dim output As Double() = network.Compute(input)

        '  Get the index of the highest probability class
        Dim imax As Double = output.Max()

        ' Result output
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
        ListBox1.Items.Add("class: " + output.ToList().IndexOf(imax).ToString)
        For Each o As Double In output
            ListBox1.Items.Add(Format(o, "0.00000"))
        Next
```

Comment: could it be, that there is an error with teacher.GetLayerInput(inputs). As I read in the code it takes inputs[0] and takes this as layerData, but that would mean only one layer of the inputs would be taken all the time. But I don't understand it completly how it should work, so maybe I'm wrong